# Only default Post Template for different Custom Post Types

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

On my current projet, I've some CPTs (~9), I would like for a part of them to use a same post template and use an other one for the other part. Until there, it's ok with this piece of code.

```
<?php 
  /* Template Name: 'Template 1'
   * Template Post Type: cpt1, cpt2, cpt3 */ 
?>
```

My problem is when I'm creating a new post. I have to choose the template each time...(> [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lk2Zq.png)) Not really convenient for my client. A repetitive handling.

Would it be possible to force a default template ? Any ideas ?

Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve what you need by setting up custom templates for your CPTs that will conform to the WP template hierarchy, and accessing the common template from within these template files.

Specifically, for the custom post types which you wish to have common templates, you could use the `get_template_part()` function within these files to access a common template structure.

### Template Hierarchy

If you name your template files appropriately, WordPress knows that the template should be used by default for a given custom post type.

For example, if you name a template file `single-product.php`, this template will be used for a custom post type registered with the slug `product`.

The templates are selected in hierarchically, so if you need to you can even have WordPress display a custom template for a specific slug. The hierarchy for custom post types is:

1. `single-{post-type}-{slug}.php` If you have custom post type {post-type} with slug {slug}, this template will be used. otherwise...
2. `single-{post-type}.php` If you have a custom post type {post-type} this template will be used.
3. `single.php` Otherwise, WP falls back to single.php
4. `singular.php` - used if there is no `single.php`
5. Finally, if there is no other option WP uses `index.php`.

In your case, you might set up the various templates individually for each custom post type, but for the templates that should be the same, reference your common template parts from *within* these templates.

For example, if you have custom post types `cpt1` and `cpt2` which should access the same template, create two templates (`single-cpt1.php` and `single-cpt2.php`) and add the following code to both of them:

```
<?php get_template_part('templates/content', 'common-cpt'); ?>
```

You can then add the common template data to a template file named `templates/content-common-cpt.php` and your problem should be solved.

### References

- [get_template_part()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_part/)
- [WordPress template hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/#single-post)

Comment: Yes, that was it. I thought it would be possible to avoid the single-{post-type}.php by just using the post templates. But I just have to combine them. Thanks for your reply !

Comment: Glad to help - you could also stick with single.php and include template parts conditionally there using `is_singular(['cpt1', 'cpt2'])`. If you're interested in logical template re-use I suggest looking at the Sage starter theme: https://roots.io/sage/